# how to Create a textbox that stores history?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im a beginner and i don't know how to make textbox that restore history.
can some one. give me a sample code. or teach me how to do it.
im using sql server as my databse.
thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean `autoComplete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Manually added some items
    lst.Add("apple")
    lst.Add("applle")
    lst.Add("appple")
    lst.Add("appplee")
    lst.Add("bear")
    lst.Add("pear")

    'Records binded to the AutocompleteStringCollection.
    MySource.AddRange(lst.ToArray)

    'this AutocompleteStringcollection binded to the textbox as custom
    'source.
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource

    'Auto complete mode set to suggest append so that it will sugesst one
    'or more suggested completion strings it has bith ‘Suggest’ and
    '‘Append’ functionality
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend

    'Set to Custom source we have filled already
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is the `autoComplete` feature, you can enable it from the textbox properties:

To set the mode:

[image]

To set the source:

[image]